# Stripe: card being declined even after changing card details

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using the test card `4000 0000 0000 0341` to test for a failed response. After charging to this source, it fails as expected. After changing the test card number to `4242 4242 4242 4242`, it still returns that my card is being declined. Only after refreshing the page and using the test card `4242 4242 4242 4242` again, then it will succeed.

I tried looking at the dashboard on stripe under the payments tab to see for both of the failed transactions, and it seems that stripe is still saving the previous card details even after changing the card number to `4242 4242 4242 4242`.

[image]

Any idea what is happening? Thank you so much in advance.

Edit: I'm using react for my frontend and the library react-stripe-elements for my react components and I'm using wordpress for my backend.
I've checked for the stripeToken for both of the failed instances, it is different. Hope this clarifies better.

Comment: try to better explain your development environment

Comment: @NineCattoRules Edited my post with information on my dev environment

Comment: @MervynLim The problem is likely not the card itself but the way you are creating the charge. My guess is that you haven't replaced the card and so it's still charging the 0341 by default